# How to pronounce "ReLU" (Rectified Linear Unit)?

Tags: pronunciation, computing

A [*Rectified Linear Unit*](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/reluICML.pdf) is a common activation function in deep neural networks and is often abbreviated as "*ReLU*".  I usually pronounce it as */**rel**-you/* (with the "e" as in "relative" or "rectified"), but I often hear colleagues pronounce it */**ray**-loo/*.

Is there a consensus on the correct pronunciation of "*ReLU*"?

Comment: However the guy who invented it pronounces it.  If I had to guess, though, I'd say "ree-loo".  It's not "rel-you" because the first syllable is obviously "Re", and it doesn't include the "L".  And "Re" by itself would be pronounced "ree", as in "repair" or "refund".

Comment: I pronounce it 'reh-loo'.

Comment: @HotLicks I have to disagree with the guy who invented it pronouncing it right (at least they don't some times, don't know about this case) gifs are definitely gifs, not *jifs*, however I would pronounce it as Mitch does

Answer (score 4):

I've always heard professors in classes I've taken at Stanford, such as CS230 and CS231N, pronounce it as /**ray**-loo/ and /**reh**-loo/, and I've always used /**ray**-loo/.

However, the lecturer in [this video](https://youtu.be/S27pHKBEp30?t=1249) uses the /**rel**-you/ pronunciation, which prompted the search that brought me here. The lecturer clearly has [extensive ML experience](http://www.leodirac.com/#/professional).

I'd hazard a guess based on my anecdotes that /**ray**-loo/ is more common, but I'd definitely say all three seem to be accepted, given the involvement all parties have in the ML community.